# Where would localForage data be stored for an iPad app?

Tags: trigger.io, localforage

I understand how localForage works in unison with a browser, but am less certain how it would interact as a part of a hybrid iPad app. There is no browser, per se, to store data in so I'm wondering if using localForage will still allow my data to be available offline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So are you familiar with what a 'Hybrid app' is?

Not to be an a-hole about but a hybrid app, by definition is a 'web view' in a wrapper. Cordova, trigger.io etc are all basically doing the same thing. Taking the native browser ( IOS and Android ) and wrapping it in the context of an 'app'

thats the short version, you can read a lot more about it online, anyhow to answer you question about localforage..

LocalForage is a 'shim' meaning its uses what ever the platform will support, so for IOS below 9 ( I think ) it will use SQLLite and over IOS 9 and above it will use indexDB. With Android and crosswalk it will use indexDB ( unless otherwise selected )

Now for devices that do not support one of the other it will fallback to localstorage but that is limited due to the total size of storage

Comment: This is actually my first attempt on a hybrid app so I'm certain there are things I should know that I don't. Since I posted this question I implemented localForage throughout the app and it's working really well. Was really more concerned that when the device was offline that it would be a pain to pull the data from indexDB. It ended up being more straightforward that I expected. Anyway, thank you for your response.

Comment: What I end up doing, and this is just for performance, is that I load up the localForage data into runtime variables when the app is open, this way I don't have to keep accessing the localForage data store.. Not that its super slow but not as fast as in-memory